# Vector, Point, Battleship, 2D

Tags: java, methods, vector, point

I shall program some methods in Java for the game battleship? Not sure how it's called in English.

We shall create the method:

```
private static Point[] createSchiff(int laenge)
```

Which creates a ship with the length `laenge`, a random position on the field and random direction, and returns a reference of the ship.

The ship shall be from the type `Point` and we shall use the object `Vector` as a container for all ships we create.

The full programmcode I have so far is:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Programm34 {
    public int anzahlschiffe=5;
    public Point[] schiffe = new Point[anzahlschiffe];
    public static void main(String[]args){



        Vector v=new Vector();

        int i=10;
        double random=0;
        System.out.println("Zufallszahlen: ");
        for(i=anzahlschiffe;i>0;i--){
            random=random(0,10);
            System.out.print((int)random+" ");
            System.out.println("");
        } //Test für random Methode!! 
        int[][] Spielfeld= new int[10][10];



        init(Spielfeld);
        for(int x=9;x>=0;x--){
            for(int y=9;y>=0;y--){
                System.out.print(Spielfeld[x][y]);
                if(y!=0){
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                if(y==0 && x!=0){
                    System.out.print("\n");
                }
            }
        }



    }




    private static long random(int u, int o){
        double random;
        random=Math.random()*(u-o)+o;
        return (int)random;
    }

    private static Point[] createSchiff(int laenge){

        point(1,2);


    }

    private static boolean positionOk(Vector<Point[]> schiffe,Point[] schiff){

    }

    private static boolean grenze(Point[] schiff){

    }

    private static boolean konflikt(Vector<Point[]> schiffe,Point[] schiff){

    }

    private static boolean nachbar(Vector<Point[]> schiffe,Point[] schiff){

    }

    private static boolean increment(Vector<Point[]> schiffe,int laenge){

    }

    private static void init(int[][] spielfeld){
        for(int i=9;i>=0;i--){
            for(int j=9;j>=0;j--){
                spielfeld[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void add(int[][] spielfeld, Vector<Point[]> schiffe){

    }
}
```

All those methods and the main shall be programmed, but what matters ist the createschiff ("createship") one.

Can you help me explain the vector? the point? And how the whole stuff works? I sit here now for like 2 hours with no progress... thx alot

Comment: I could not make any sense out of this. Even title is not informative. Voting to close.

Comment: What is unclear? I tried best to explain my problem. I shall create a method which creates a ship, This ship shall be from the type Point, contained in a Vector. I asked for help and you just close it? Thats sad...

Comment: @user3556093: You haven't explained what you want to do, what you have already done, and why it isn't what you want.

Comment: i explained, i have to create a method which creates a ship with the lenght of "laenge" for the game battleship. This ship, or those ships, shall be from the type point. And i shall use a Vector, which contains all those ships. I need help with the Points and the Vector as i dont understand how those things work, even with 2 hours spent on research.

All that is written in the text above. Also eclipse tells me that the method point(int,int) is undefined, but why? I importet the class, didnt i?

Answer (score 1):

First a minor (but helpful) thing: You should add generics parameters to the vector. (I doubt that it is necessary to use `Vector`. A `List` should be sufficient. But when it is in the assignment, you have to do it...)

```
Vector<Point[]> v=new Vector<Point[]>();
```

About the `createSchiff` method: You' have to create several `Point` objects. Namely, one for each field that is covered by the ship. This could roughly look like this:

```
private static Point[] createSchiff(int laenge)
{
    int positionX = ... // Some random position
    int positionY = ... // Some random position

    // Create the array that will contain the fields
    // covered by the ship:
    Point result[] = new Point[laenge];

    // Fill the array
    for (int i=0; i<laenge; i++) 
    {
        result[i] = new Point(positionX, positionY);

        // Change the position for the next field,
        // depending on the direction of the ship:
        positionX += ...
        positionY += ...
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then you can call this method like this:

```
Point ship[] = createSchiff(3);
v.add(ship);
```

(I could insert more real code instead of the placeholders `...` , but you should try this on your own)

Comment: I thank you a lot, i think that already helps me :)